# Draggable rectangle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to have a rectangle on my map canvas, that can be dragged. How can I achieve this? Is it possible with QgsRubberBand? The rect should look like this:

[image: Rect]

The user should not be able to resize it. And I want to initialize it with map coordinates.

Comment: Hi. Please read these guidelines and edit your question to include recommend information: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'draggable'? Do you mean, be able to move it around the map canvas, to achieve...... what? I'm missing something here. Is this rectangle just a graphic? Or is it like a selection mask?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the `QgsRubberBand` class. You also need to subclass `QgsMapTool` and override it's methods such as `canvasPressEvent()`, `canvasMoveEvent()`, `canvasReleaseEvent()`, and `deactivate()`.

Here is an example:

```py
class RectangleTool(QgsMapTool):
    
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.project = QgsProject.instance()
        self.rb = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
        # Define coordinates of top left & bottom right corners of rectangle
        # These are in geographic coordinates
        self.tl = QgsPointXY(0.2, 44.5)
        self.br = QgsPointXY(2.7, 42.5)
        # Create a rectangle from top left & bottom right points
        # Here we also transform the rectangle to the project CRS so it renders correctly on the canvas
        self.rect = self.transform_rect(QgsRectangle(self.tl, self.br))
        self.geom = QgsGeometry.fromRect(self.rect)
        self.rb.setToGeometry(self.geom)
        self.rb.setStrokeColor(QColor(75, 190, 165))
        self.rb.setFillColor(QColor(75, 190, 165, 75))
        self.rb.setWidth(0.5)
        self.rb.show()
        self.moving = False
        self.start_point = None
        self.new_point = None
        self.tl_x_offset = None
        self.tl_y_offset = None
        self.br_x_offset = None
        self.br_y_offset = None
            
    def transform_rect(self, rect):
        xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('epsg:4326'), self.project.crs(), self.project)
        return xform.transform(rect)
        
    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        # Check if the mouse click is inside the rectangle
        if QgsGeometry().fromPointXY(e.mapPoint()).intersects(self.geom):
            self.start_point = e.mapPoint()
            # Calculate the offset from click point to top left/bottom right corners
            self.tl_x_offset = self.rect.xMinimum() - self.start_point.x()
            self.tl_y_offset = self.rect.yMaximum() - self.start_point.y()
            self.br_x_offset = self.rect.xMaximum() - self.start_point.x()
            self.br_y_offset = self.rect.yMinimum() - self.start_point.y()
            # Set condition to true. We will set back to False when mouse is released
            # This means that rectangle will only be dragged when the mouse button is held down
            self.moving = True
        
    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.moving:
            # Reset the rubber band
            self.rb.reset()
            self.new_point = e.mapPoint()
            # Define new top left/ bottom right corners relative to current cursor position on canvas
            self.tl = QgsPointXY(self.new_point.x()+self.tl_x_offset, self.new_point.y()+self.tl_y_offset)
            self.br = QgsPointXY(self.new_point.x()+self.br_x_offset, self.new_point.y()+self.br_y_offset)
            self.rect = QgsRectangle(self.tl, self.br)
            self.geom = QgsGeometry.fromRect(self.rect)
            self.rb.setToGeometry(self.geom)
            self.rb.show()
                
    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        # Set condition to False
        if self.moving:
            self.moving = False
    
    def deactivate(self):
        # Remove the rubber band when the custom tool is deactivated
        self.rb.reset()
        
t = RectangleTool(iface)
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(t)
```

Result:

[image]